# Aggregate unique values of a column based on group by multiple columns and count unique - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
ID col1 col2    col3
I1 1    0       1 
I2 1    0       1 
I3 0    1       0 
I4 0    1       0 
I5 0    0       1
```

This is my dataframe. I am looking forward to aggregate ID values based on the group by of col1,col2,col3 and also want a count columns along ith this.

Expected output :

```
ID_List      Count 
[I1,I2]       2
[I3,I4]       2
[I5]          1
```

My code

```
cols_to_group = ['col1','col2','col3']
data = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(cols_to_group)['id'].nunique()).reset_index(drop=True)
data.head()

   ID
0  2
1  2
2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `groupby.agg()`:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'], sort=False).ID.agg([list,'count'])
```

Output:

```
                    list  count
col1 col2 col3                 
1    0    1     [I1, I2]      2
0    1    0     [I3, I4]      2
     0    1         [I5]      1
```

Comment: nice one, i'd add `reset_index(drop=True)` to match OP requirement

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate a function by either sum, count etc. In this case, count. Try the below code.

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).ID.agg([list,'count']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    list    count
0   [I1, I2]    2
1   [I3, I4]    2
2   [I5]    1
```

Comment: this is exactly the same as Quang's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
grouped = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], sort=False).ID
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID_List': grouped.aggregate(list),
    'Count': grouped.count()
}).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ID_List  Count
0  [I1, I2]      2
1  [I3, I4]      2
2      [I5]      1
```